# Start matched element id with 0 using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have lots of span tags in the document. I want give span element id which has "check" text inside and it should start with 0 like: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ugj5Z/)

```
<span>not check</span>
<span>not check</span>
<span id="0">check</span>
<span id="1">check</span>
<span id="2">check</span>
<span>not check</span>
<span id="3">check</span>
<span id="4">check</span>
```

My JavaScript code is as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $('span').each(function(i){
        $(this).filter(function(){
            if( $(this).text().trim()=='check'){
                $(this).attr('id',i);
                $(this).attr('class',$(this).index())
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: So do want to set id from 0...n for the span tags which has 'check' as text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim()=='check';
}).attr('id', function(i,oldVal) {
    return i;
});
```

You don't need an `.each()` loop if you just want to set the `id`. First filter, then pass a callback function to `.attr()` - it will be called for each item and passed the zero-based index of the current item, which is, conveniently, the value you want for the id so just return it.

Answer (score 4):

Filter them first and *then* set their attributes:

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'check';
}).attr('id', function(index) {
    return index;
});
```

`.index()` (and the `index` argument to callbacks) is the index of the element in the set of matched elements, which is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Working Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/Ugj5Z/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text().trim() == 'check';
    }).attr('id', function (i) {
        return i;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$(function(){
    var lastIndex = 0;

    $('span').each(function(){
        $(this).filter(function(){
            if( $(this).text().trim()=='check'){
                $(this).attr('id',lastIndex++);
                $(this).attr('class',$(this).index())
            }
        })
    })
})
```

See my fork of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ugj5Z/1/

Comment: So what is that `.filter()` call actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

use closure for that

```
$(function(){
var i = 0;
    $('span').each(function(i){
        $(this).filter(function(){
            if( $(this).text().trim()=='check'){
                $(this).attr('id',i++);
                $(this).attr('class',$(this).index())
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you explain what your call to `$(this).filter()` does?